# Javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

Can anyone explain the meaning of the assign operator? What does it mean?
It came out as true but I'm unclear on how we reached to there.

Thanks!

```
var x = 0 !=1;
```

Comment: zero is not equal to one. This shouldn't be surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Order of operations (`var x = (0 != 1)`)**

Imagine you computed just `0 != 1`. This is evidently a true statement, so this would evaluate to `true`. If you set `x` to the evaluation of `0 != 1`, then you receive `var x = true`.

Comment: Thank you! It's seems clear to me now

Answer (score 4):

An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand. In this case **true** will be assigned to the variable **x** as 1!=0 (1 not equal-to 0) is **true**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I didnt think of order of operations when checking that.